# Best way to opt out of layouts in nested routes in next13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

By reading Next13's docs for their new app router I came to the conclusion that parantheses can be used for different layouts. For instance:

```
app
  (withLayout)
     page.tsx
     layout.tsx
  about
     page.tsx
```

While this works, it becomes a pain if you would like to opt out of a layout in a more nested path. For instance:

```
user
  (profileLayout)
    courses
      drafts
        page.tsx
    profile
      page.tsx
    layout.tsx
  courses
    drafts
      new
        page.tsx
```

In this example, I want `/user/courses/drafts/page.tsx` and `/user/profile/page.tsx` to have the same layout, but the more nested `/user/courses/drafts/new/page.tsx` to ignore this layout. Is the structure above really the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is a bit hacky but it should work for you. The only downside is you have to make your layout a client component.

```js
"use client"

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'


export default function Layout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const pathname = usePathname()

  if (pathname !== "/user/courses/drafts/new") {
    return (
      <html>
        <body>
            <SomeComponent/>
            <div>
              {children}
            </div>
        </body>
      </html>
    )

  } else {
    return (
      <div class="">
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So what is happening here is that if the pathname is not the path you want to ignore, then you render the layout you want. But if the pathname is the one you want to ignore, then you can opt out with the `else` statement.

Comment: this approach will only work for nested layouts and not the root layout. The root layout is a Server Component by default and can not be set to a Client Component.

Comment: Yeah, that's true.